# Mongoid Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm having a problem where i'm trying to reference a model called user twice from a comment model.

The first instance is because a user can have many comments (as recipient)

But the other association is a comment has one author. Is that

```
references_one :user, :inverse_of :author
```

Would I then need another association in user for comments by that user as opposed to for that user.

```
embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :commentsout
```

I hope it makes a bit of sense.

Maybe something like this makes more sense (pseudo-code)

```
user:
   has_many: comments => author
   can_be: author, recipient

comment:
   belongs_to_many: users => recipients
   has_one: user => author
```

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is like http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid but in my instance i have a user model rather and a author model and in it's a devise user so i can't embed user in a comment as an author. perhaps i need an author model that can be embedded but references_one user model as inverse_of :author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly you can define the associations like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document      
  field :name,  :type => String      
  references_many :comments, :inverse_of => :author
  references_and_referenced_in_many :comments_received, :class_name => 'Comment', :inverse_of => :recipients
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document    
  field :text, :type => String
  referenced_in :author, :class_name => 'User'
  references_and_referenced_in_many :recipients, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :comments_received
end
```

If the target cannot be inferred from the association name you need to add a :class_name parameter. This makes it possible to have multiple associations to the same class.

Comment: thank you so much, i was using inverse or class_name at some point. didn't think about putting them together, and didn't know about references_and_referenced_in_many. awesome.